# @rxweb/reactive-form-validators Decorator Based Validation vanishing translators in form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-translate

#context 
  I have added formControlName as in the model name,it was working fine.After adding translations it stopped working and behaving weirdly,i am not getting what is causing the problem to vanish the #translation.If i uncomment some subscheme div in my html translations will be back.

## angular translator #reactive-forms #model-based

//Component

```
    import { RxFormBuilder } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';
    import { ReactiveFormConfig } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-sob-create-update-action-plan',
      templateUrl: './create-update-action-plan.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./create-update-action-plan.component.scss']
    })
    export class CreateUpdateActionPlanComponent implements OnInit {

      actionPlanFormGroup: FormGroup;
      actionPlanDetails: ActionPlanModel;

      constructor(
        private formBuilder: RxFormBuilder
    ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        ReactiveFormConfig.set({
          validationMessage: {
              required: 'This field is required',
          }
      });
        this.actionPlanDetails =  new ActionPlanModel();
        this.actionPlanFormGroup = this.formBuilder.formGroup(this.actionPlanDetails);
      }

    }

    Model class 

    import { required, compare, maxLength } from '@rxweb/reactive-form-validators';

    export class ActionPlanModel {

       private year: number;
       private scheme: number;
       private subScheme: number;
       private grantingAllocationOrderNo: number;
       private district: string;
       private ULBName: string;
       private schemeGrant: string;
       private grantOrderNo: string;
       private grantOrderDate: string;
       private grantOrderAmount: string;
       private actionPlanApprovalNo: string;
       private actionPlanApprovalDate: string;
       private grantAmountForSelectedSubScheme: string;
       private approvalAmount: string;


        public getYear(): number {
            return this.year;
        }

        @maxLength({value: 50 })
        @required()
        public setYear(year: number): void {
            this.year = year;
        }

        public getScheme(): number {
            return this.scheme;
        }

        @maxLength({value: 50 })
        @required()
        public setScheme(scheme: number): void {
            this.scheme = scheme;
        }

       //I have setters and getters for all the fields like above
     constructor(){}

    }
```

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-group"><label>{{ 'Create.SubScheme' | translate }} <span class="imp_star">*</span></label><select class="form-drop input100 form-control" data-live-search="true"  formControlName="subScheme" >
 <option value="Select ">Select </option>
</select></div> <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 form-group">
<label>{{ 'Create.SubScheme' | translate }} <span class="imp_star">*</span></label><select class="form-drop input100 form-control" data-live-search="true"  formControlName="subScheme" ><option value="Select ">Select </option></select></div>

Comment: Comment i posted my HTML snippet

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz link of your code and please check if there is any error in the console.